# How to untarget a JDBC resource using wlst script?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I am trying to untarget a JDBCResource in weblogic using wlst script.

I tried the following:

```
cd('/JdbcSystemResource/DataSource1')
set('Targets',jarray.array([], ObjectName))
```

but it fails with the following exception:

```
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Param type [Ljavax.management.ObjectName; not supported
```

Why does it say ObjectName not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i was trying in an offline mode and from one of the oracle documents i found that we can use unassign function to untarget in an offline mode

```
 cd('/JDBCSystemResources/'+ dsName)
 targets = cmo.getTargets()
 for target in targets:
     unassign("JDBCSystemResource",dsName, "Target",target.getName())
```

Comment: Jinu, unassign command, this would be the answer that you found for your question? Please select right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the target, you can remove it explicitly with something like:

```
startEdit()
cd('/JDBCSystemResources/myDS')
jdbcDS=cmo
cd("/Servers/server1")
target=cmo  
jdbcDS.removeTarget(target)
```

If you don't know the targets, that is easy to find out as well:

```
cd('/JDBCSystemResources/myDS')
cmo.getTargets()
```